# Замены строки

Tags: php

Есть файл, в нем допустим 100 строчек, этот файл я открываю через file, fopen, file_get_contents или еще как и сохраняю все в переменную $X. Далее проделываю тоже самое но с другим файлом, но с меньшим кол-во строк, например 5 и сохраняю все в переменю $Y. 
так вот как удалить из переменой $X строки или символы $Y
пробывал $X=str_replace($Y, "", $X) или циклично пробежатся по строкам, но никак не получается :(((

дело в то что нужно учесть что в переменой $X в какойто то строке для замены, могут быть еще другие символы, приведу пример

```
$X="
abcdefg
abc
dsc
fghh
sdf
abc
dsc
fgt
dgh
sdgabc
dscfgh
"

$Y="
abc
dsc
"
```

на выходе должно быть

```
$X="
abcdefg //нужно учитывать точную последовательность символов

fghh
sdf

fgt
dgh
sdg 
fgh
"
```

в идеала, там где был переход на новую строчку, поднимался на строчку вверх т.е.

```
$X="
abcdefg

fghh
sdf

fgt
dgh
sdgfgh"
```

Comment: Сделайте  

    trim($Y)
и применяйте Ваш способ замены из текста вопроса.  

    $X=str_replace(trim($Y), "", $X);

Comment: ну это уж точно работать не будет :)

Comment: @Александр Лукин, я не ленивый :) Где теория- там и практика.  

    <pre>
    <?
    $X=<<< HEREDOC
    abcdefg
    abc
    dsc
    fghh
    sdf
    abc
    dsc
    fgt
    dgh
    sdgabc
    dscfgh
    HEREDOC;

    $Y=<<<HEREDOC

    abc
    dsc

    HEREDOC;
    echo str_replace(trim($Y), "", $X);
    ?>
    </pre>
Результат:  

abcdefg

    fghh
    sdf
    
    fgt
    dgh
    sdgfgh
Результат отличается от желаемого самым малом, но в контексте Вашей задачи **удалить вирус** это не принципиально, так как вирус пишет целыми тэгами.

Comment: А точнее, от Вашего идеала результат отличается всего на один перенос строки в конце текста.  
Вы бы хоть проверили для приличия.

Comment: оставил так ты сказал, только без трима в принципе с этого я и начал. но это тоже не 100% рабочий вариант. 
просто ты меня не доконца понял. но все равно спасибо

1)нужно учесть что после удаления, допустим если чиста происходит не в html а в js, то внутри допустим document.write("..вредоносный код..") били переносы, поднимались навверх
2)часть вредоносного кода может хранится в строке вместе с нормальным текстом
3)вирус с табуляцией (вроде фигня но не так все просто на практике сидеть в текстарея вставлять теги \t и пробелы не так сладко)

Comment: и многое другое

насчет проверки извени, просто меня смутило trim(), он же чистить все переносы и лишние пробелы, а мне нужно полное совпадение. а проверить тоже не очень хочется, т.к. требует многое времени.
щас скрипт висит на хосте, где есть 20 сайтов. он быстро сканить все что есть в паблике и заносить в базу около 300 тыс. файлов, дальше включить в логику новое условие и пропустить на проверу, чето не хочется тратить время :((((

Comment: трим гораздо быстрее выполнится, чем цикл, так как трим это один нативный вызов, а цикл с перебором строк это куча нативных вызовов.  
Да и не в том месте Вы ищете прирост производительности.

Answer (score 3):

Первый файл считываете построчно в массив.
Второй файл считывает построчно также в массив.
Далее к общему массиву из фдвух файлов применяем array_unique(); Получаем массив уникальных значений, если я правильно понял постановку задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Зоркий правильно говорит, но дополню:
После того, как получили два массива, вложенными циклами делаем следующее:

1. берём 1 строчку второго массива
2. сравниваем её с каждой строчкой второго массива
3. если они равны - удаляем, если нет, ничего не делаем
4. переходим ко 2 строчке второго массива

ну и всё, вроде всё просто. или я не так понял?

Comment: @Dazar. ???

     берём 1 строчку второго массива
     сравниваем её с каждой строчкой второго массива

Comment: нене не все так просто, посмотрите на пример по внимательнее нужно именно последовательность строчек заменять. Просто как вы говорили уже делал :(((

Допустим вирус вставляет такой код

<body>\n
<script>...</script>\n
</body>\n

и так штук 10-20 в каждый php файл, так мне нужно чтоб скрипт удалял именно 3 эти строчки, но не трогал верхний боди или нижний или если вдруг вставился другой вредоносный код, но часть этого кода если входит в основной код тоже както анализировался.